# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un jtable a campos de otro internalframe?

Tags: java, java-swing

Ya sé cómo hacer que los datos de un jtable pasen a textfield, pero no sé cómo hacerlo cuando el textfield o combobox está en otro internalframe.

Aquí está el código que he utilizado para pasar los datos, pero me envía el dato a una nueva ventana y no a la anterior.

```
private void btnEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int seleccionado= tabla_Status.getSelectedRow();
    if(seleccionado == -1){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes seleccionar una fila");       
    }else{
        Equiponewin eqps = new Equiponewin();
        if(eqps.isShowing()==false){

            this.getDesktopPane().add(eqps);
            eqps.toFront();
            eqps.setVisible(true);
            
            Equiponewin.txtIDsteq.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(seleccionado, 0).toString());
            Equiponewin.txtStatuseq.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(seleccionado, 1).toString());
            
        }else{
            Equiponewin.txtIDsteq.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(seleccionado, 0).toString());
            Equiponewin.txtStatuseq.setText(tabla_Status.getValueAt(seleccionado, 1).toString());
        }              
    }
    
}
```

Aquí la imagen de lo que pasa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: listo  y lo puse

Comment: he escuchado que por medio de un ArrayList se podría pero no se como funciona el ArrayList